# save Image as PNG

Tags: java, image

I'd like to save from my array a point chart as Image(PNG), with this Java Program I can show my Schatter Diagram but I don't know how to save it. Perhaps with ImageIO.write, and how? 
can anybody give me some advice to solve this problem. Thank you

```
public class Graph extends Application {

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
Pane root = new Pane();
int[] mydata = {
        12, 9, 0, 1, 38, 19, 21, 72, 33, 83, 14, 10, 65, 46, 10, 17, 27, 38, 65, 98, 8, 58, 38, 79, 37, 69, 26, 15};

        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
ScatterChart scatterChart=new ScatterChart(xAxis,yAxis);


XYChart.Series data=new XYChart.Series();
for (int i=0; i< mydata.length; i++) {
    data.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i,mydata[i]));
}       
 scatterChart.getData().addAll(data);


root.getChildren().add(scatterChart);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();

File file = new File("c:\\Images\\Image.png");

// and now ?????

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw your plots or diagram onto an Image like BufferedImage. Save the BufferedImage as a file after that. You can try something like that:

```
class MyScatterPlot
{
    private BufferedImage buf;

    //Constructors, initializations not shown.

    public void saveBufferAsImage(String pathname){
        String fmt = "";
        if(!(pathname == null || pathname.equals(""))){
            fmt = pathname.substring(pathname.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
            File outputfile = new File(pathname);
            try{
                ImageIO.write(buf, fmt, outputfile);        
            }catch(IOException ioe){System.out.println("Unable to save file");}
        }       
    }

    public void drawImage(){
        buf = new BufferedImage (200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = buf.createGraphics();   
        g2d.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 150);  //draw your image here (example only)
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

To save the diagram as an image file (such as `.png`):

```
MyScatterPlot plot = new MyScatterPlot();
plot.drawImage();
plot.saveBufferAsImage("MyGraph.png");
```

Comment: Thank you, 
How can I increase my graph? if I set Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 500); I become the same size.

Comment: You can just scale your graph accordingly when you draw it. Just add some calculations to it, for example set a ratio in accordance to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-2-snapshot-as-png-image/), you need code:

```
...
//and now
WritableImage image = scatterChart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
try {
  ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO: handle exception here
}
```